# How do I write 'this' less often?

Tags: javascript

Using ES6 classes is great and all, but I find myself using this.variable everywhere, and it is always referring to my class. Is there a way to have implied globals within my class be implied this.variable instead? So if I write 'width' it will be defaulted to this.width instead of an implied global?

Or if there are some best practices that I might not be aware of to cut down on my 'this' addiction I'd love to read that too. In the file I'm currently working on there are about half as many this keywords as there are lines of code...

Comment: `this` is good!

Comment: Using `this` means that you use of proper encapsulation. There is nothing to get rid off in here. If you don't like it, it means that you do not like OOP. You can look at others languages.

Comment: @JeBokE I know that but I want window to be my class instead. If I could somehow set the 'implied global' to be 'implied class variable' I could make my code so much shorter and prettier ;-;

Comment: I guess you are coming from one of the languages where using this is optional (shudders). In my opinion, not using this in languages where it is optional makes it harder to read the code when you also work with languages where this is mandatory especially if you also work with languages where variables are created on the fly if they don't exists.

Comment: @rypskar I come from Java, if Int someNumber = 1 and somewhere else in my class I write someNumber it will assume that I mean this.someNumber unless there is a more local someNumber like a parameter in the method

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159146/discussion-on-question-by-odin-thorsen-how-do-i-write-this-less-often).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using constructor functions / classes and `this` is just one way to use JavaScript. JavaScript is a multi-paradigm language and yes, it's entirely possible to use it largely without using `this`. One way is via closures.

Consider this `class` example:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.things = [];
  }
  sayHello() {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.first} ${this.last}`);
  }
  grabThing(thing) {
    this.things.push(thing);
  }
}
const p1 = new Person("Joe", "Bloggs");
p1.sayHello();
p1.grabThing("thing1");
console.log(p1.first + "'s things: " + p1.things.join(", "));
const p2 = new Person("Suresh", "Kumar");
p2.sayHello();
p2.grabThing("thing2");
p2.grabThing("thing3");
console.log(p2.first + "'s things: " + p2.things.join(", "));
```

Now, consider this approach with closures:

```js
function createPerson(first, last) {
  const things = [];
  return {
    sayHello() {
      console.log(`Hi, I'm ${first} ${last}`);
    },
    grabThing(thing) {
      things.push(thing);
    },
    get things() {
      return things;
    },
    get first() {
      return first;
    },
    get last() {
      return last;
    }
  };
}
const p1 = createPerson("Joe", "Bloggs");
p1.sayHello();
p1.grabThing("thing1");
console.log(p1.first + "'s things: " + p1.things.join(", "));
const p2 = createPerson("Suresh", "Kumar");
p2.sayHello();
p2.grabThing("thing2");
p2.grabThing("thing3");
console.log(p2.first + "'s things: " + p2.things.join(", "));
```

Notice how we just use the `first` and `last` parameters provided to the `createPerson` function directly in `sayHello`, and we just declare `things` as a local constant which `grabThing` closes over. In that example, we also provide getters for the various bits of information (`first`, `last`, `things`) so they can be used from the object we return, but if there were information we wanted to keep private, we could leave out the getter. (And some prefer to make those explicitly functions rather than getters.)

One downside to this approach is that there are separate function objects for `sayHello`, `grabThing`, the getters, etc., for **each** object created by `createPerson`, while in the `class` example, there's only one `sayHello` function object, which is shared amongst `Person` objects via prototypical inheritance. On the one hand, creating additional `sayHello` function objects seems wasteful; but modern JavaScript engines reuse the underlying function code even though there are distinct `sayHello` objects, and objects are fairly cheap in our modern world.

Upsides are the easy way to have private information and not having to use and manage `this`.

Douglas Crockford (amongst others) promotes this approach, if you want to learn more about it. (Note that in his writing, Crockford sometimes fails to clearly distinguish between fact and his opinion — and boy does he have opinions — but his writing is well worth reading regardless.)

(I'm not advocating either `class` or non-`class`, just noting there are options.)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but it doesn't really solve my problem, I know I want to use classes but I just wish there was a way to imply this instead of having to write it 300 times in a file with 600 lines. But judging from the other replies I guess it's impossible :\

Comment: @OdinThorsen: Well, this pattern would be one of the alternative practices you mentioned. :-) But no, JavaScript has no implied `this` concept (a Good Thing™ in my view). There is a convoluted way to do it in loose mode (working around the fact that `class` code is always strict), but modules will soon be where 99.9% of code will live and modules are always strict as well. If it's a length thing, you can always do `const t = this;` at the top of a function and then use `t.` instead of `this.` (and then you continue to get the benefit of auto-suggestions in an IDE), but... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a recommended practice, but a [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement is sortof what OP asks for.

`with` allows parsing an object, using the attributes as variables within the statement:

```js
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function() {
  function MyClass(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  MyClass.prototype.whoami = function() {
    with(this) {
      console.log(name, age);
    }
  };
  return MyClass;
}());
var c = new MyClass("bob", 123);
c.whoami();
```

There is the issue that `with` is disabled in `strict mode` though, meaning that there are [some contexts where it simply won't work](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1135).

ES6 classes is one such context, so if OP want's to use ES6 classes, then `with` is out.

Comment: Yes like you said it won't work, but I appreciate the contribution nonetheless, always nice to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at this old question the answer has become obvious with the release of hooks, just don't write class components and write function components instead :)